# Load Loop when add load event listener to object element

Tags: typescript, angular8

When I add a function to listen when data in Object Element is loaded this enter in a load infinite loop

this only happens in Angular 8, before I use same code in Angular 4, 6 y 7 and work correctly

component.template.html

```html
...
 <object #object [data]="_data" (load)="onObjectLoaded()"></object>
...
```

component.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('object', { static: true }) object: ElementRef<HTMLObjectElement>;
...
   onObjectLoaded() {
    this.svg = 
     this.object.nativeElement.contentDocument.querySelector('svg');
    this.onLoadObject.emit(true);
  }
...
```